# "No input file specified." after installing Roundcube

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian, roundcube

I'm configuring a new vps (Debian 7), after installing apache, php, and phpmyadmin. I am now trying to install roundcube but I am getting a blank page with the message `"No input file specified."` when trying to access it online.

**I got the following error in the logs:**

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/roundcube/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/clients/client0/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client0/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client0/web1/tmp:/var/www/site.com/web:/srv/www/site.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin) in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to disabled `open_basedir` both in the `php.ini` and the conf file for apache but I still get this error (I restarted apache). Maybe open_basedir is not the problem; permission, symlink?

---

**apache.conf:**

```
# Those aliases do not work properly with several hosts on your apache server
# Uncomment them to use it or adapt them to your configuration
#    Alias /roundcube/program/js/tiny_mce/ /usr/share/tinymce/www/
#    Alias /roundcube /var/lib/roundcube

Alias /interfacewebmail /var/lib/roundcube

# Access to tinymce files
<Directory "/usr/share/tinymce/www/">
      Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/lib/roundcube/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    php_admin_value open_basedir none
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    </FilesMatch>

    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
    Options +ExecCGI

  # This is needed to parse /var/lib/roundcube/.htaccess. See its
  # content before setting AllowOverride to None.
  AllowOverride All
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>

# Protecting basic directories:
<Directory /var/lib/roundcube/config>
        Options -FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/lib/roundcube/temp>
        Options -FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/lib/roundcube/logs>
        Options -FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

the clue is in the error message

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. 

File(/usr/share/roundcube/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
```

So what you need to do is to add the roundcube path into the "allowed" paths

See this on how to do just that [PHP open_basedir broken in Apache but works in PHP at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053948/php-open-basedir-broken-in-apache-but-works-in-php-at-runtime)

LE:
It would help if you changed this

```
php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

into

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/usr/share/roundcube/"
```

Comment: It didn't work, so I decided to switch roundcube for Horde and got an "internal server error" instead of the "No input file specified.". I Solved this by editing the min_uid in suphp.conf on the www-data UID and now it works.